# Is there any way to change source-port in javamail during send mail?

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-mail

Is there any way to change source-port in javamail during send mail? In Transport.send() , javamail uses socket default port as source port to send mail. Can I change the source port?

Answer (score 1):

Set the ["mail.smtp.localport" property](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but for this to work, both of these properties need to be set:

`mail.smtp.localaddress` and `mail.smtp.localport`.

This is due to the underlying JavaMail implementation in `com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher` which uses `mail.smtp.localport` property only if `mail.smtp.localaddress` is set.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to change the source port during sending mail. But there are various Sub classes of Transport which provide the protocol specific wrapper for sending mail . for example SMTPTransport is the class to be used for SMTP protocol. Use something like

```
SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");    
transport.connect();    
transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

Comment: Wrong, and the suggestion about Transport doesn't answer the question either.